# Webbrowser closing in WFA c#

Tags: c#, winforms, webbrowser-control

I'm doing a interactive periodic table in Windows forms application in c#

When I click on say Hydrogen it pops out a wiki webpage with everything about Hydrogen, however when I press another say Sodium, it will open up wiki (but if it's too slow at the moment) I might see Hydrogen till the Sodium page loads.

I tried to do webbrowser.Stop() but no success. I don't mind the loading time but I mind seeing the element I was checking out before. Any help?

Also is there, a way to disable further navigation once the page is opened. Say i opened Hydrogen on wiki there's tons of other links to visit.

Comment: webbrowser.Stop() will stop loading the current navigation. So after that call you would never see Sodium if the page isn't loaded yet. What do you wanna show the user while the navigation is loading? If you dont wanna show Hydrogen, will you show a blank screen instead?

Comment: Periodic table perhaps till it loads up ? Can the screen from webbrowser tool be transparent till it loads up a webpage?

Comment: You could use WebBrowser.Hide() while it's loading and WebBrowser.Show() if it's done. Btw it should be possible to set WebBrowser.AllowNavigation = false to disable further navigation until page is loaded

Comment: There's a DocumentCompleted event you can catch and show the webbroser again

Comment: @Nitro.de here's the part of the code, I'm having some trouble with DocumentCompleted event: http://www.deviantpics.com/images/2016/03/08/Capture.jpg

Comment: You're using the delegate wrong here. You're using `new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs` but you need to use `WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler`. If you see [**here**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowserdocumentcompletedeventhandler(v=vs.110).aspx) you should notice that the handler expect args not the other way around

Comment: @nitro.de Thanks I'm all done it has nice transition now, it won't show up till it loads so I don't get to see pages loaded before. And till it loads theres only periodic table to look at :)